# What could cause RSpec to fail when a controller test sees a view file with a _path helper only when when running the entire suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1

After upgrading a project from Rails 6.0 to 6.1, RSpec has been failing on any controller or request spec that ends up with a view file that contains any form of `_url` or `_path` helper.

The most simple example could be written as;

```
it 'gets blah' do
  get '/blah'
end
```

If `/blah` just had some text on it, nothing would blow up, however if we add `<%= root_path %>` to that view (and root is set) then I will get this error;

```
Failure/Error: <%= root_path %>

      ActionView::Template::Error:
        wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 0..1)
```

This is the same for pretty much any path helper I've found. The issue was initially found because `form_with(modal: blah)` was failing because `polymorphic_mappings` can't be called on `nil`, some digging in the Rails code would suggest it wasn't loading any of the routes.

To make things more confusing;

- `rspec` fails
- `rspec spec/controllers/specific_spec.rb:33` passes
- `rspec spec/controllers/specific_spec.rb` passes
- `rspec spec/controllers/` passes
- `rspec spec/` fails

The code running under `development` works as expected, it is only under test we see the issues.

Comment: If full suite fails, but specific test alone passes, then that indicates your tests not being independent of each other. Run `rspec --bisect` to figure out exactly which test order causes the failure, then you can investigate how they tests are related and how they're leaking state from one to the other.

Comment: @SiimLiiser, thanks! That is what I initially thought, but everything works on 6.0 and even when these tests are the first to run they fail. Which would maybe suggest it isn't a leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow, so in one of our test files someone (normally git blame points fingers at me, strangely not this time!!) had added

```rb
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Which presumably has changed between 6.0 and 6.1 so including this file does *something*.

Unlike other tests I've seen fail based on the order they ran, because this sits at the top of a file, no order would pass so long as RSpec loaded in the file.

tl;dr, don't include url_helpers in your test this way!